# Как сравнить цифровые значения enum?

Tags: java, enum

Как создать `enum` с числами? И как сравнивать их между собой?

P.S. У меня была система "рейтинга", которая была в числах `1, 3, 9`.
Точнее, был `ArrayList` с объектами класса, в это классе было поле с рейтингом.

В конце рейтинг разных объектов сравнивался, и выбирался с наибольшим рейтингом.

Мне посоветовали "держать" рейтинг используя `enum`. Но что-то создать enum с числами не получается, как в этом [примере](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792110/java-enum-return-int) тоже.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class EnumInt {

    enum Rating {
        ONE(1), THREE(3), NINE(9);

        private final int value;

        Rating(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Rating.THREE.getValue() < Rating.NINE.getValue()); // true
    }
}
```